# checkbox to select item of a row table and get the amount that the user input in the from

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I want to use a checkbox to select items of a row table but i am having problem to get the amount of each item that the user input in the from here is my html code. I would like to use php someone can help me?

```
<form id="RegisterUserForm" action="register.php" method="post">

                    <table id="t01">
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%">Select</th>
                            <th width="20%">Picture</th>
                            <th width="55%">Description</th>
                            <th width="10%">Amount</th>
                            <th width="10%">Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input id="pedido1" name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 1</td>
                            <td id="imagem1"><img src="imagen1.png"></td>
                            <td>Descriptiondo Product 1</td>
                            <td><input id="qt" name="qt" type="text" class="text" value="1" /></td>
                            <td>13.50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input id="pedido1" name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 2</td>
                            <td id="imagem1"><img src="imagen2.png"></td>
                            <td>Descriptiondo Product 2</td>
                            <td><input id="qt" name="qt" type="text" class="text" value="1" /></td>
                            <td>13.50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input id="pedido1" name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 3</td>
                            <td id="imagem1"><img src="imagen3.png"></td>
                            <td>Descriptiondo Product 3</td>
                            <td><input id="qt" name="qt" type="text" class="text" value="1" /></td>
                            <td>13.50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input id="pedido1" name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 4</td>
                            <td id="imagem1"><img src="imagen4.png"></td>
                            <td>Descriptiondo Product 4</td>
                            <td><input id="qt" name="qt" type="text" class="text" value="1" /></td>
                            <td>13.50</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                        <button id="register" type="submit">register</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but why do you have a check box and amount in the same form? I mean, if all amounts start with 0 (or blank) and the user changes to another number, its clear that he wants that product.

Then you can work only with this parameter in your form (each one having specific name, probably containing the id of the product). Something like:

```
<form>
    //rest of html
    <input name="qt[idproduct]" type="text" class="text" value="" />
    //rest of html
    <input name="qt[idproduct]" type="text" class="text" value="" />
    //rest of html
    <input name="qt[idproduct]" type="text" class="text" value="" />
    //rest of html
</form>
```

The input of this form will result an array parameter `qt` where you can get the values by:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['qt'])) { //or $_POST
        foreach ($_GET['qt'] as $id => $total) {
            if(!empty($total) && $total > 0 && is_numeric($total)) { // just checking if you are receiving a number bigger than 0
                echo "Product: " . $id . " total: " . $total . "<br />"; // do your thing
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE**

and with `checkboxes`, form:

```
<form>
    //rest of html

    <input name="check_list[idproduct1]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 1
    <input name="qt[idproduct1]" type="text" class="text" value="" />
    //rest of html

    <input name="check_list[idproduct2]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 2
    <input name="qt[idproduct2]" type="text" class="text" value="" />

    //rest of html

    <input name="check_list[idproduct3]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Product 3
    <input name="qt[idproduct3]" type="text" class="text" value="" />

    //rest of html
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['check_list'])) { //or $_POST
        foreach ($_GET['check_list'] as $id => $value) {
            $total = $_GET['qt'][$id];
            if(!empty($total) && $total > 0 && is_numeric($total)) { // just checking if you are receiving a number bigger than 0
                echo "Product: " . $id . " total: " . $total . "<br />"; // do your thing
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it's the menu of my restaurant.....so if the cliente wants 2 pizzas of the same type he can select the type and the amount of pizzas he wants, i would like to put the check box because it will be more clear from my clientes....is it possible to do that?

Comment: I see, updated the answer with the checkboxes. Btw, try to avoid repeating same id on each input, its a bad practice.

Comment: thanks a lot this already helps....but i have another question.....is possible to put the price of the product in the checkbox value....and then make a calculation like: totalprice=product1_price*amount+product2_price*amount
and echo total price....another thing i was using everthing just with html until now so no coneccting with database yet

Comment: The original price of each single product you will get from the information stored in your db, sure. But show the prices changing when the customer add another product or increase the amount you will do with `js`, there is no need to check the db each time for that.

Comment: I was thinking to use the checkbox to select the id row to kown which produtc is but how can i get the amount of pizzas the users types? i don't undestand anything about js so i was trying to avoid it....maybe is time to learn something........i think this ideia could work what do you think?